# Bios Versions? Changelog

Tags: bios, history, phoenix

Where could one find a feature list or change log for Phoenix Bios? How would one compare and contrast versions? My search of the company's site and web have turned up very little.

F.3D and F.39 if numbered hexadecimally are separated by four versions. The only know variation between mentioned versions is that the fan algorithm has been changed from previous versions.

Comment: Never did find much information: "The new BIOS release for your notebook PC is preventative in nature to reduce the likelihood of future system issues. The BIOS updates the fan control algorithm of the system, and turns the fan on at low volume while your notebook PC is operational. If you are currently experiencing any symptoms on your notebook PC, please contact HP for support." 
While not much information, F.39 is implied for the series machine; and I had the wrong one. I feared something similar to a NDA, trade or proprietary knowledge. But not having dealt with bios much…ThankYou Both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to find this information.

Typically, motherboard manufactures sign a NDA with the BIOS companies and have access to source code and binaries of the latest versions. They are able to release updates at will, however the version numbers do not always add up and they are usually only released to fix problems as and when they are found.

You are unlikely to find a complete changelog for any BIOS but simply see what the new release directly fixes. For example from a random Asus motherboard:

[image]

However, remember, you are a customer and they want your business! You have nothing to lose by emailing and asking them.

Answer (score 1):

the Phoenix BIOS version is irrelevant, it's only a platform. you will have to check with the motherboard manufacturer, most of them update a changelog for their BIOS upgrades with the motherboard specification sheet. it's up to the manufacturer which features they make accessible for a particular mainboard. so, even if 2 motherboards have the same Phoenix BIOS version, that doesn't necessarily mean they do have the same features.